# how to call subquery inside WHEN Clause - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

i have two tables :

**Product** :

```
id name  category
1  AAA    BBB
2  CCC    DDD
3  EEE    FFF
```

**Ordre**:

```
id id_product     date
1      2       10/11/16
2      2       06/16/16
3      3       12/09/16
4      1       02/06/16
5      3       15/10/16
```

in order to know if a product has an order i create this select query :

```
SELECT id,name ,category 

CASE WHEN id IN (select id_product from Ordre) then 'Y'
       ELSE 'N' END AS has_ordre

FROM product;
```

but this is not working for me, in the fact i want to create a View that contains the info about the products and also has the column "has_ordre" to check if a product has an ordre or not.

do you have any suggestion?
i'm new in Mysql
thanks in advance.

Comment: you  missed  a comma  after category   .. try  SELECT id,name ,category , CASE WHEN ...

Comment: thanks @scaisEdge you are rigth i missed the comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you need without a sub-query by doing a join on the two tables and a COUNT() on order.id_product, which will count the number of orders for each product. NOTE: this query will completely (as designed) exclude products which have no orders. Also, the result for this particular query will show the number of orders for each product:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.category, COUNT(o.id_product) AS num_orders
FROM product p
    RIGHT JOIN order o
        ON p.id = o.id_product
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY num_orders
```

You can change the RIGHT JOIN to a LEFT JOIN if you would like to display all orders regardless of whether or not they have an active order:

[**Here is a fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9905a3/3/0)